# Temporary Sprite in Android App

Tags: java, android, iteration, sprite

I have an android game where there are sprites moving about the screen.  When one is hit, it adds or takes away from the score and then disappears.

What I would like it to do is create a blood splatter when it is hit which will also disappear.

I have actually achieved this but the blood splatter doesn't appear where the sprite was hit.  It always goes to the bottom right-hand corner.  I was wondering if there is anyone out there that can see where my problem is.

I have a TempSprite class just for the blood splatter and this is below:

```
public class TempSprite {

private float x;
private float y;
private Bitmap bmp;
private int life = 12;
private List<TempSprite> temps;

public TempSprite(List<TempSprite> temps, GameView gameView, float x,
                  float y, Bitmap bmp) {
    this.x = Math.min(Math.max(x - bmp.getWidth() / 2, 0),
            gameView.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth());
    this.y = Math.min(Math.max(y - bmp.getHeight() / 2, 0),
            gameView.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight());
    this.bmp = bmp;
    this.temps = temps;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    update();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
}

private void update() {
    if (--life < 1) {
        temps.remove(this);
    }
}

}
```

All the other code is in the GameView class, specifically in the doDraw and GameView methods:

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private final Bitmap bmpBlood;
/* Member (state) fields   */
private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
private Paint paint; //Reference a paint object
/** The drawable to use as the background of the animation canvas */
private Bitmap mBackgroundImage;
// For creating the game Sprite
private Sprite sprite;
private BadSprite badSprite;
// For recording the number of hits
private int hitCount;
// For displaying the highest score
private int highScore;
// To track if a game is over
private boolean gameOver;
// To play sound
private SoundPool mySound;
private int zapSoundId;
private int screamSoundId;
// For multiple sprites
private ArrayList<Sprite> spritesArrayList;
private ArrayList<BadSprite> badSpriteArrayList;
// For the temp blood image
private List<TempSprite> temps = new ArrayList<TempSprite>();

//int backButtonCount = 0;

private void createSprites() {
    // Initialise sprite object
    spritesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    badSpriteArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        spritesArrayList.add(new Sprite(this));
        badSpriteArrayList.add(new BadSprite(this));
    }


}

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // Focus must be on GameView so that events can be handled.
    this.setFocusable(true);
    // For intercepting events on the surface.
    this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    // Background image added
    mBackgroundImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.castle);
    // Populate multiple sprites
    //createSprites();
    //Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) sprite.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    //vibe.vibrate(500);
    // For the temp blood splatter
    bmpBlood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blood1);
    //Sound effects for the sprite touch
    mySound = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    screamSoundId = mySound.load(context, R.raw.scream, 1);
    zapSoundId = mySound.load(context, R.raw.zap, 1);


}

/* Called immediately after the surface created */
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    createSprites();
    // We can now safely setup the game start the game loop.
    ResetGame();//Set up a new game up - could be called by a 'play again option'
    mBackgroundImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), true);
    gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this.getHolder(), this);
    gameLoopThread.running = true;
    gameLoopThread.start();
}



// For the countdown timer
private long startTime; // Timer to count down from
private final long interval = 1 * 1000; // 1 sec interval
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // Reference to the class
private boolean timerRunning = false;
private String displayTime; // To display the time on the screen


//To initialise/reset game
private void ResetGame(){
    /* Set paint details */
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(20);
    sprite = new Sprite(this);
    hitCount = 0;
    // Set timer
    startTime = 10; // Start at 10s to count down
    // Create new object - convert startTime to milliseconds
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime*1000, interval);
    countDownTimer.start(); // Start the time running
    timerRunning = true;
    gameOver = false;


}



// Countdown Timer - private class
private class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    public MyCountDownTimer (long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //displayTime = "Time is up!";
        timerRunning = false;
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        gameOver = true;
    }
    public void onTick (long millisUntilFinished) {
        displayTime = " " + millisUntilFinished / 1000;
    }
}


//This class updates and manages the assets prior to drawing - called from the Thread
public void update(){


}

/**
 * To draw the game to the screen
 * This is called from Thread, so synchronisation can be done
 */
@SuppressWarnings("ResourceAsColor")
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

    if (!gameOver) {

        sprite.draw(canvas);
        //paint.setColor(R.color.red);
        canvas.drawText("Time Remaining: " + displayTime, 35, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Number of hits: " + hitCount, 35, 85, paint);
        // Draw the blood splatter
        for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
        }
        // Draw all the objects on the canvas
        for (int i = 0; i < spritesArrayList.size(); i++) {
            Sprite sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
            sprite.draw(canvas);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < badSpriteArrayList.size(); i++) {
            BadSprite badSprite = badSpriteArrayList.get(i);
            badSprite.draw(canvas);
        }
    } else {
        canvas.drawText("Game Over!", 35, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("Your score was: " + hitCount, 35, 80, paint);
        canvas.drawText("To go back home,", 280, 50, paint);
        canvas.drawText("press the 'back' key", 280, 70, paint);
    }


}


//To be used if we need to find where screen was touched
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    for (int i = spritesArrayList.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
        Sprite sprite = spritesArrayList.get(i);
        if (sprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
            mySound.play(zapSoundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0,0, 1.5f);
            spritesArrayList.remove(sprite);
            //temps.add(new TempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpBlood));
            hitCount--;


            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        for (int i1 = badSpriteArrayList.size()-1; i1>=0; i1--) {
            BadSprite badSprite = badSpriteArrayList.get(i1);
            if (badSprite.wasItTouched(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                mySound.play(screamSoundId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.5f);
                badSpriteArrayList.remove(badSprite);
                temps.add(new TempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpBlood));
                hitCount++;


                return super.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        }
    }
    //else {
    return true;
    //  }
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    gameLoopThread.running = false;

    // Shut down the game loop thread cleanly.
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            gameLoopThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}

public int getHitCount() {

    return hitCount;

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}


}
```

As always, any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This was solved with the following code:

```
public class TempSprite {

private float x;
private float y;
private Bitmap bmp;
private int life = 12;
private List<TempSprite> temps;

public TempSprite(List<TempSprite> temps, GameView gameView, float x,
                  float y, Bitmap bmp) {
    /*this.x = Math.min(Math.max(x - bmp.getWidth() / 2, 0),
            gameView.getWidth() - bmp.getWidth());
    this.y = Math.min(Math.max(y - bmp.getHeight() / 2, 0),
            gameView.getHeight() - bmp.getHeight());*/
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.bmp = bmp;
    this.temps = temps;
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    update();
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, x, y, null);
}

private void update() {
    if (--life < 1) {
        temps.remove(this);
    }
}

}
```

You can see where the commented out sections are and below are what they were replaced with.  I was trying to make things a little too complicated.